# Spark SQL - Values from multiple columns into a single column

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I need to convert Tabular One data to Tabular Two data. SaleCounts belongs to particular customer or customerId despite have multiple row entries should be put into a single cell with comma seperated. Please see the below for better understanding.

Input - Tabular Column 1 (columns are space seperated):

```
Customer    Cid     SaleCount
1           1       10
1           1       20
1           1       50
2           4       40
2           4       100
3           56      90
```

Output - Tabular Column 2 (columns are space seperated):

```
Customer    Cid     SaleCount
1           1       10,20,50
2           4       40,100
3           56      90
```

Answer (score 3):

In Spark SQL I don't think FOR XML PATH works, instead please try:

```
SELECT Customer, Cid, concat_ws(', ',collect_set(SaleCount)) as SaleCounts
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY Customer, Cid
ORDER BY Customer, Cid
```

Which should give you what you're looking for above.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below approach:

```
SELECT  Customer,Cid,
   STUFF( 
                  (SELECT ', ' + cast( d2.SaleCount as varchar(100)) FROM t1 d2
                    WHERE d2.Customer = t1.Customer and  d2.Cid = t1.Cid
                   ORDER BY Customer, Cid
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''
        )
FROM t1

GROUP BY Customer, Cid
```